How do I send an image while the image is still containing Caption and Inline keyboard?
class TgSender:
    TOKEN = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')

    @staticmethod
    def tgSendImage(chat_id, photo_path, keyboard=None, caption=None):
        TELEGRAM_API_URL = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TgSender.TOKEN}/sendPhoto"
        try:
            with open(photo_path, 'rb') as photo:
                files = {'photo': photo}
                data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'parse_mode': 'HTML'}
                if caption:
                    data['caption'] = caption
                if keyboard:
                    data['reply_markup'] = keyboard.to_dict()
                response = requests.post(TELEGRAM_API_URL, files=files, data=data)
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:", e)
            return e

I did this,
async def SendImageMessage(chat_id, photo_path, keyboard=None, caption=None):
    reply_markup = None
    if keyboard:
        reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    response = TgSender.tgSendImage(chat_id, photo_path, reply_markup, caption)
    print(response.status_code)
    return response

and I called the SendImageMessage as such
async def dash_buttons(request: Request):
    data = await request.json()
    chat_id = data["message"]["chat"]["id"]
    fname = data["message"]["chat"]["first_name"]
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(" Main Menu! ", callback_data="main_menu"), #  ለመጫወት         
        ]
    ]
    photo_url = 'assets/img/9rwq9asd4rymrq9823hf.jpeg'
    message_text = "Welcome!"
    response = await SendImageMessage(chat_id, photo_url, keyboard, message_text)    
    print(response.status_code)

I don't know what happened but when I sent the image without the keyboard, it does work but with the keyboard, it just returns 400. And the inline keyboard mechanism works since I've used it many times on other projects but when it comes to sending an inline keyboard, it just stops working.
Is there something I should know that I haven't tried?

Can you share what's the response body content? You've shared the 400 status code. Telegram server will also send you a status message text along with the error. It'll help in debugging.

I've tried to replicate the issue, but,  it seems sending photo with caption and keyboard works pretty fine for my end. So, it should work fine for you as well. From what I can see from code, I'm assuming it's something with the added inline keyboard. Please share more info so that we can continue debugging.
